# How to get f(x)=kx+d form of linear regression line?

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, linear-regression

I have a data frame `dt.Data` with time data (values of this data frame are changing each day) and I'm plotting an correlation scatter plot and the regression line with `ggplot()`. The R code looks like this:

```
set.seed(123)

## Create data frame: ##
df.Data <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date('2018-01-01'), by = '1 day', length.out = 1100),
                      DE = rnorm(1100, 2, 1), AT = rnorm(1100, 5, 2))
corPearson <- cor.test(x = df.Data$DE, y = df.Data$AT, method = "pearson")

df.Data$year <- format(as.Date(df.Data$date), '%Y')

p <- ggplot(data = df.Data, aes(x = DE, y = AT, group = 1)
      ) +
      geom_point(aes(color = year)) + 
      geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "#007d3c") +
      theme_classic() +
      theme(legend.position = "none") +
      theme(panel.background = element_blank()) +
      scale_colour_brewer(palette = 'Greens') + 
      xlab(product1) +
      ylab(product2) +
      ggtitle("Correlation Scatter Plot (Pearson)") +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"))

# Correlation plot converting from ggplot to plotly: #
CorrelationPlot <- plotly::ggplotly(p, tooltip = "text")
```

The regression line is plotted with: `geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "#007d3c")`.

The plot looks like this:

[image]

My question now is:
How do I get the function of the regression line in the form **f(x) = kx + d**? I have already seen this question a few times in stackoverflow, but no answer there was complete or useful. Can someone help me?

**EDIT:**
If I use this

```
reg <- lm(df.Data$AT ~ df.Data$DE)
summary(reg)
```

the output of the summary is:

[image]

where the `d=5.07667` (red) and `k=-0.03306` (blue)? Is this correct?
How can I extract both values and construct a function like this: `f(x)=kx+d=-0.3303x+5.07667`??

I need this `f(x)` as an output of a `valueBox()` in a RShiny app.

Comment: If you have seen this question around then this will probably be flagged as a duplicate. The better idea might be to put a bounty on one of those questions for a better answer (But I feel your pain at the idea of using bounties because I too would feel the pain of using my rep for one)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with bounty?? I'm new to stackoverflow

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties I just realised you are 14 rep from being able to do so but this is an explanation of bounties in the help center

Comment: @TheGrandJ oh okay, now I understand. Thank you for this information and link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `lm()` function:

```
reg <- lm (df.Data$AT ~ df.Data$DE)
summary (reg)
```

When you summarize you can see the intercept, which is your d and the slop which is you k.
Let me know if this helps :)

Comment: Thank you, this works. I have edited my question now, are the d and k values the right one? How can I build my function ```f(x)=kx+d```?

Comment: You can use `predict()` function. Which predics the values with the function you mentioned. If you want to do it manually you have to extract the coefficients out of the enviroment.

Answer (score 0):

For new predictions you can use the predict function.

Tip:
For predictions on new data you have to provide for the "newdata" argument in the predict function a data.frame with the same column names as in your formula. But if you fit your model in the following way:

```
reg <- lm (df.Data$AT ~ df.Data$DE)
```

You would have to create a new data.frame with the column name 'df.Data$DE' which is irritating.

Using the "data" argument from the lm function is more convenient:

```
reg <- lm(AT ~ DE, data = df.Data)
predict(reg, newdata = data.frame(DE = 2.0))
```

Tip:
If you are only interested in the coefficients of the model, you can also use the 'coef' method:

```
reg <- lm(AT ~ DE, data = df.Data)
coef(reg)
```